# Class list - How would I make this repeat to the amount of students entered?

Tags: python-3.x

How would I make this repeat to the amount of students entered? Everything I've tried doesn't work.

```
numStudents = input("Enter the number of students: ")

while true:
    for x in range(len(numStudents)):
        name = input("Student Name: ")
        number = input("Student Number: ")
```

ex.

```
Enter the number of students: 3

Student name:
Student Number:

Student name:
Student Number:

Student name:
Student Number:
```

Comment: `len(numStudents)` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Also no need for `while true`

Comment: Inputs will take input as `str`, so you have to cast it to integer: `int(input (....))` first.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Get rid of the `while true:` (it's called `True` in Python, and there's no reason for an infinite loop even if you fixed that)
2. Replace `for x in range(len(numStudents)):` with `for x in range(int(numStudents)):` to loop `numStudents` times, rather than looping "length of the string stored in `numStudents`" times. Or just change `numStudents = input("Enter the number of students: ")` to `numStudents = int(input("Enter the number of students: "))` to make it an `int` from the get go, and make the `for` loop `for x in range(numStudents):`